# JasperReports bug with subDataset

Tags: jasper-reports

I am encountering a very problematic behavior which defeats the purpose of using sub data sets altogether.

Whenever I just declare subDataSet:

```
<subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="b8a31d7f-9906-4db0-ac81-155091b1817a">
        <parameter name="Parameter3" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["SELECT country, count(*) AS number_of_sites FROM sites GROUP BY country ORDER BY number_of_sites DESC LIMIT 5"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[$P{Parameter3}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="country" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="number_of_sites" class="java.lang.Long"/>
</subDataset>
```

and use it in barChart(or stacked BarChart to be precise, but it does not matter) :

```
           <categoryDataset>
                <dataset>
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1" uuid="0a388bb3-2e57-4880-9b48-27e0a2afd415"/>
                </dataset>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{country}]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{country}]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_of_sites}]]></valueExpression>
                    <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_of_sites}.toString()]]></labelExpression>
                </categorySeries>
            </categoryDataset>
```

I get empty document as a result, I am 100% sure that report adapter works correctly. So to run this and get results I need for some reason to additionally include the duplicate entries:

```
<parameter name="Parameter3" class="java.lang.String">
                <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["SELECT country, count(*) AS number_of_sites FROM sites GROUP BY country ORDER BY number_of_sites DESC LIMIT 5"]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[$P{Parameter3}]]>
</queryString>
```

This is added somewhere outside the subDataSet block in JRXML. This again makes me desperate as I encountered so many jasper bugs or inconsistencies in design. If main query needs to match the subDataset then this defeats the purpose of multiquerying inside the report. In my case I don't even need main report query I want to have many subdatasets each having its own query.

I played with report connection it does not change anything, the results come back only and only when main query match subDataset query along with the parameterization. If any of the 4 components not match - it either fails to generate report or returns empty document.

I played with uuids making them match - which makes zero difference.

Comment: If you use something like "select 1" as a query for your main dataset, would it work? I believe the Jasper Reports environment wouldn't create any bands (for your main report) if you don't have a query for your main dataset.

Comment: You are correct, post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the Jasper Reports environment wouldn't create any bands (for your main report) if you don't have a query for your main dataset.

You can try something like "select 1 as dummy" for your query for example.

The Jaspersoft Studio offers as an option a data source called "One Empty Record". It may be useful for your purpose as well.